# How to enable email for notifications?

Tags: facebook, notifications, email-notifications

I'm developing a prototype on Facebook and want to ensure that if they want, users can get an email along with the regular Facebook notification.  This has been specifically requested from some of my users who don't spend a lot of their time on the site, and have their notification settings really tight, but do check their email regularly.

I've enabled all the settings I can find,
[image: app settings]

[image: notif settings]

[image: email settings]

But still nothing.

Even though Facebook seems to give you the option, is there no way to do this, because I see that most other apps who email me directly generally do it from their own domain / email account, rather than through the Facebook messaging system.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After obtaining the `email` extended permission (which it looks like you have) just retrieve the email address using the graph api, or fql, and then send the email yourself.  That's how it works.  There is no way to send email using the Facebook api.

Comment: +1; there was an API for this but it's super-deprecated, in a 'if this breaks, it'll stay broken' sort of way

Comment: Thanks for that Pat, but I was aware of this solution already, I wanted some way as either a user or developer to have Facebook email me when I got a notification.  All of their UI suggests you have that option, so my thought was there was possibly a difference in how notifications were sent.  Ah well, I'll leave this a few days, then accept your answer if it's confirmed there's no other way.